# Virtualizing desktop environment for other guests

Tags: desktop, virtualization

I am using virtual box.  Consider I am having 4 guest OS (Linux)  mounted over the Host(Win 7 )

I am trying to virtualize the desktop environment in one of the guest OS and allow the other 3 Guests to access that desktop.

Pls help me with the method to do that. What all will i require to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have your cloud server set up, this could be as simple as making sure that everybody involved has the right password and login information and making sure that you grant access to "all users." Ensure that the Linux user has admin authority and you should have no problems. There have been issues with users of different versions of windows not being able to access the same server, but assuming that your Windows users are all on the same OS, there should be no such problem.

http://content.dell.com/us/en/enterprise/virtualization